# how to solve math variable in python? having trouble with =

Tags: python, math

h = 10 
w = 550

## I want to solve for x

(8 * x) + (h - 8) * (x * 1.5) = w

# then i want to print answer

print answer

Comment: What did you try so far? Maybe `print("x = 50")` is the code you need?

Comment: step one get the variable you want to solve for alone ... (ie step1=> factor x out of the left hand side ...

Comment: This is an algebra problem.  Python does not natively solve equations for you.  You can research algorithms to solve linear equations symbolically, or through functional means, but that requires that you clarify the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If you want to solve this equation algebraically with python, you want the `sympy` package. If you want to print what the result, you have to rearrange it yourself and just print that rearranged equation on python.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only pseudo code was presented along with demands.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to solve you can always use sympy (but i suspect you are looking for something else)

```
>>> from sympy.solvers import solve
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> x=Symbol('x')
>>> h,w=10,550
>>> eqn = 8*x + (h-8)*(x*1.5) - w
>>> solve(eqn,x)
```